# Is HPE AMD EPYC compatible with AMD EPYC in custom-built systems?

Tags: processor, motherboard

As everyone here likely knows, the chip shortage is making it hard to get all kinds of CPUs. I'm in need of an 8-, 12, or 16-core 7002-series AMD EPYC processor (socket SP3). They are hard to come by. However, I've noticed two things: It's easier to find in-stock "HPE AMD EPYC" processors, and they tend to be a lower price. From the looks of it, this is an OEM processor for Hewlett-Packard Enterprise ProLiant servers. However, it also appears to still be socket SP3. So what I'm not clear on is, are HPE AMD EPYC processors compatible with AMD EPYC processors?

In other words, were I to buy an HPE AMD EPYC 7262 CPU, would it work in my Supermicro MBD-H12SSL-i-O AMD EPYC 7002 SP3 2TB DDR4 PXIE SATA ATX motherboard just as well as a retail AMD EPYC 7262 CPU? Or would it be incompatible for some reason? The specs all look identical (unless the specs are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is the same and model number is the same, the compatibility is the same.